# DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION API: Incorrect Japanese Character Recognition

Tags: google-cloud-vision

We are using the Vision API's OCR service (DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION). However, since around 9:00 AM (JST) on March 8, 2024, we have noticed that some Japanese (JA) text is being recognized as old Japanese characters.

For example, the character "内" (nai) is being recognized as the old form "內" (nai). This is not happening for all old characters, and sometimes the standard Japanese character is returned.

This issue has not occurred in the past. Additionally, for documents that were recognized with old characters after March 8, 2024, subsequent recognitions will also return results with mixed old and new characters.

We have checked the response locale. Initially, we thought that this issue only affected the "und" locale, but we have confirmed that it also occurs with the "ja" locale.

Has there been a recent change to the internal algorithm?

If there is any solution to this problem, please let us know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Additional Information:**

- Language: Japanese (JA)
- OS: Windows
- ENDPOINT: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
- SDK: REST

**Reproducible Body:**

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "CLOUD_STORAGE_IMAGE_URI"
        }
       },
       "features": [
         {
           "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
内閣府
```

**Actual Output:**

```
內閣府
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this page.
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes?hl=ja

The December 5 update was reflected in stable on or about March 8.
In our project, Japanese is also misidentified as Chinese.

Comment: We've been having a problem relating to Cloud Vision API WEB_DETECTION calls since about March 16. I suspect that something has changed in this update that's causing previously successful calls to return an HTTP 200 but empty result. Thought it's not related to Jananese character recognition, I'm commenting here because this is the first report I've found with a timeframe that matches ours.

Comment: I also found an open issue on Google's issue tracker related to Japanese character detection:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/320282943

Comment: Well, just to close this side-loop. Our API calls to WEB_DETECTION that were returning an empty result yesterday and causing errors in our code are now returning the expected data for exactly the image. and everything seems to be fine. So - I guess Google fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a language hint like in https://b.corp.google.com/issues/320282943#comment5

You can also try your image with version builtin/weekly https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#feature